# Unexpected semi-colons in conditional

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have the following line of code which when compiled with GHC it goes without a hitch:

```
addRDF c (Just (FILE))  = do
  (_:file:_) <- getArgs
  check <- doesFileExist file
  if check then do rdfG <- TLI.readFile file >>= (return . parseN3fromText)
                   case rdfG of (Left s)  -> putStrLn s
                                (Right g) -> storeRDF c g
  else do putStrLn "Specified files does not exist"
```

But when I run it through the cabal build process, it dumps out the following error.

```
Repository/Adder.hs:46:35:
    Unexpected semi-colons in conditional:
    if check then do { rdfG <- TLI.readFile file
                             >>=
                               (return . parseN3fromText);
                       case rdfG of {
                         (Left s) -> putStrLn s
                         (Right g) -> storeRDF c g } }; else do { putStrLn
                                                                    "Specified files does not exist" }
Perhaps you meant to use -XDoAndIfThenElse?
```

I can see the additional semicolon in the error but I don't understand where that comes from.

Here is my cabal configuration file:

```
cabal-version: >= 1.2
build-type: Simple

library
  build-depends:
    base,
    containers,
    HTTP >= 4000.2.2,
    directory >= 1.1.0.0,
    text >= 0.11.1.13,
    swish >= 0.6.5.2
  exposed-modules: Repository.Adder, Repository.Configuration
  ghc-options: -Wall

executable repository-add
  main-is: repository-add.hs
  build-depends:
    MissingH,
    swish >= 0.6.5.2,
    split >= 0.1.4.2
  ghc-options: -Wall
```

**UPDATE**

With correct indentation for `if`:

```
addRDF c (Just (FILE))  = do (_:file:_) <- getArgs
  check <- doesFileExist file
  if check
  then do rdfG <- TLI.readFile file >>= (return . parseN3fromText)
          case rdfG of (Left s)  -> putStrLn s
                       (Right g) -> storeRDF c g
  else do putStrLn "Specified files does not exist"
```

I get a semicolon after `check` now as well:

```
Repository/Adder.hs:46:35:
    Unexpected semi-colons in conditional:
        if check; then do { rdfG <- TLI.readFile file
                                  >>=
                                    (return . parseN3fromText);
                            case rdfG of {
                              (Left s) -> putStrLn s
                              (Right g) -> storeRDF c g } }; else do { putStrLn
                                                                         "Specified files does not exist" }
    Perhaps you meant to use -XDoAndIfThenElse?
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your indentation is incorrect, but it works when you use the raw GHC compiler because it automatically turns on the syntactic extension mentioned in the error message (`DoAndIfThenElse`).

In Cabal, you have to specify the language extensions that you use manually, either at the top of your code files, or in your Cabal files; otherwise, they will not be enabled by the compiler.

One correct version of the indentation for if-clauses is like this:

```
if check
  then do
    rdfG <- TLI.readFile file >>= (return . parseN3fromText)
    case rdfG of
      (Left s)  -> putStrLn s
      (Right g) -> storeRDF c g
  else putStrLn "Specified files does not exist"
```

You have to keep the `then` part and the `else` part at deeper indentation levels than the block they're a part of.

Comment: Interesting, I've thought of something similar but adding `extensions: DoAndIfThenElse` to my cabal file didn't have any effect.

Comment: Updated my post because the indentation fix didn't solve the problem :|

Comment: @mhitza: I believe I've corrected the if-then-else indentation issue.

Comment: @mhitza Did you add the `extensions: DoAndIfThenElse` directive in both your `library` *and* your `executable` block? Due to a (perhaps surprising) intended behavior of cabal, your executable is not using the `Repository.Adder` module from the library, but from the raw source.

Comment: @DanielWagner funny how sometimes whitespace syntax can beat you on the ass (especially for someone coming from a shell functional style, where the construct has `if` and `then` on the same line)

Regarding your question: no, I haven't, I've added it just to the `library` block, didn't seem intuitive for it to have any relation with the executable block (since calls where in the opposite direction).

Comment: @DanielWagner `Due to a (perhaps surprising) intended behavior of cabal, your executable is not using the Repository.Adder module from the library, but from the raw source` Or due to my lack of real experience with modules; PEBKAC

Comment: With recent versions of Cabal, specifying that extension explicitly is no longer necessary. This question was posted during an interval of a few years in which Haskell 2010 (and, as a consequence, `DoAndIfThenElse`) was the default for GHC but not for Cabal.